# Why does the title on a page link to the page itself on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, homepage

I noticed just now, as I was trying to select some text in the title. Is this intentional? What is its purpose?

Could be a bug, but I'm not sure so I'll tag as discussion for now.

Comment: If you have a tag filter active it is not to itself, but to the unfiltered, noisy full site

Comment: I like it because I can use right-click and "Copy link location". I find it faster than "share".

Comment: I think it's on purpose. My theory: It's a quick way to open the question in another tab so you can have the original question up while editing it. It could also be for folks whose browser settings prevent the page from updating itself.

Comment: cross-site dup of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47653/244519

Comment: @Oriol I use right-click and "Copy link location" for the "share" button, which is fast _and_ gives a short URL.

Answer (score 2):

There are many different url's for the same page. For example, my [comment that was left above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298175/why-does-the-title-on-a-page-link-to-the-page-itself-on-stackexchange-sites#comment214371_298175) , my [answer that you're now reading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299660/3041194). There's also more than one url to the same post, for example your question is also reached by [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298175), which isn't very informative when sharing the link with someone, so instead I could click on your question title to get the actual title part in the url.

There is also parameters that are sometimes added like when clicking on a link in the related questions list, for example `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281295/does-the-so-community-view-itself-as-gender-neutral?rq=1` Notice the rq=1. So lets say if I go to that question from this page, that's fine, it will correctly mark in some database that a user visited that question from your question. But lets say I want to show that gender question to other people. Instead of incorrectly using the rq=1 link, I could just click on the title's question to link to the url without the rq=1 parameter, since the people that click on the link I provide really didn't get the link from the related questions list.

Same question was asked 5 years ago on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47653/why-does-the-question-title-link-to-itself-on-the-answer-page)