# I rejected an edit that got approved by others. Can I re-edit it?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Someone [edited a question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18215894) to, for some unknown reason, replace all instances of "they" and "their" with "he" and "his". Essentially the opposite way around to how people normally edit things these days, by intentionally making it non-gender-neutral. The user's comment was "I fixed the grammar a bit."

I opted to reject the edit because it's not fixing grammar, it's just a pointless edit to force gender into a question that wasn't asking for that to be done. However, two other people accepted the edit and therefore it went through, even though I believe they made the wrong decision.

So, does this mean the consensus should just be accepted? If I then edited it to bring it back to its original (and I assume that would be accepted because I don't think people are massively critical when it comes to review queues), would that be against the rules of having a democratic reviewing process?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160963/discussion-on-question-by-matt-fletcher-i-rejected-an-edit-that-got-approved-by).

Answer (score 68):

The edit is just garbage, it doesn't make any sense and should not be approved. Not because of some sort of gender-neutral policy, but because it is a completely pointless edit.

In this case it is definitely appropriate to go back and rollback the edit, if you have the user privileges to edit/rollback posts.

---

What's more alarming here is that the people who approved the edit seem to be perfect examples of robo-reviewers:

> - User A has approved 112 edit suggestions and rejected 11 edit suggestions and improved 0 edit suggestions
> - Matt Fletcher has approved 11 edit suggestions and rejected 5 edit suggestions and improved 4 edit suggestions
> - User C has approved 52 edit suggestions and rejected 1 edit suggestion and improved 5 edit suggestions

It is normal to have an accept/reject ratio of roughly 50/50, plus/minus 25% or so. Your own accept/reject looks perfectly normal, while the two other users have unnaturally high accept ratios. They are very likely "robo-reviewers", who just always click accept to gain badges etc. Supposedly they should get automatic bans, but some people learn to dodge that system.

When you notice such cases, you can flag the post with custom reason such as:

> I suspect that the users that accepted this edit are "robo-reviewers", given their high accept ratio. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18215894

Then a diamond moderator can investigate further.

---

In addition, if you suspect that there is a crazy person running around and doing pointless edits from "their" to "his" all over SO, you definitely need to flag that for moderator attention. But you need to have a bit of proof before doing so, so reading through the most recent edits of that person before flagging might be wise.

Comment: Very good point. Glad I am not a robo-reviewer! I just want S.O to be less filled with rubbish

Comment: IIRC the moderators like to have several examples of robo-reviewing. As a rule of thumb, look for 3 recent bad reviews by the same reviewer. It's labor-intensive but more likely to get the reviewer suspended. If they Approved a spam edit, then that single Approval is enough to get them suspended.

Comment: Wait, are you claiming there is a substantial number of non-robo reviewers on SO?

Comment: The review counts have been proven to be useless for identifying robo-reviewers. Some reviewers simply skip instead of reject for example. In this case even, User C has improved 5 edit suggestions, which would signal to me that they are not a robo-reviewer. This looks like two _new_ reviewers to me.

Comment: Um, my ratio is quite heavily in favour of rejects...

Comment: @TinyGiant It's not useless, it's just a heuristic.  It's not conclusive proof, but it's reason to investigate further because a highly skewed ration is *suspicious* and has a reasonably high *probability* (not certainty) that the user isn't reviewing properly.

Comment: Be careful when deciding whether someone is a robo-reviewer simply based on whether they have a low rejection rate.  Sometimes people are like me and can't bring themselves to reject edits (with the negative impact that will have on the proposer) if they don't actually **harm** the post, so they just press Skip and go on to find good or bad edits instead, allowing someone else (who may not be autistic) to reject the edit if they like.  My accept rate is about 5 times my reject rate for that reason - but I don't consider myself a "robo-reviewer".

Comment: (Note: I'm not saying that **you** would automatically think a person was **definitely** a robo-reviewer - nothing in your post suggests that is the case - but I just want to insert a note of caution in case someone else reads this answer and thinks "ahh - 85% accept, 15% reject - must be robo-reviewer".)

Comment: How do I check my review stats? Activity - all actions - review only shows a list and a total number. How many of reviews I've rejected? I am curious about the number after @TinyGiant comment. But if I compare [robot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/709897/alexander-tyapkov?tab=activity&sort=reviews) with [myself](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997232/sinatr?tab=activity&sort=reviews) there is a clear difference.

Comment: @Sinatr That only method I know is to go back check a review that you have finished. The stats are then listed for all of the reviewers.

Comment: @Lundin, indeed, it's there, thanks! P.S.: my ratio is 4:3 (accept to reject).

Answer (score 26):

> [...] would that be against the rules of having a democratic reviewing process?

No. Sometimes people make mistakes and vote without carefully considering the edit, and we **should** fix such mistakes.

Regarding this specific post, I think that the edit was pointless and even wrong (if it was the opposite direction, maybe it's acceptable somehow), so I rolled it back.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll bear that in mind for the future then! I've only just been granted my 2k editor rights (the poweerrrrr) and wanted to make sure I wouldn't be doing anything wrong by over-ruling others' decisions.

Comment: Note that you don't want to get in edit wars. As a general rule, rollback only once. If the other editor edits your rollback again, either get a mod involved (if it's something serious like defacement or spam), or leave it be.

Comment: Note that the 2 approvers have a 10% and 2% reject rate, which is very low and likely means that they accept far too many edits without looking. A reject rate of around 50%  (or more) is much more reasonable given the quality of many of the edits we get.

Comment: Hmm, the proper approach to a useless edit can't be another useless edit.  Surely the better approach is to teach reviewers to do a better job.  Posting a link to the meta question as a comment on one of their posts is all it takes.

Comment: @HansPassant True, but rolling back is not necessarily useless. I agree about posting a link, could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

According to the answers to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78799/349538), the reason why it requires two reviewers to approve or reject an edit is to not rely on one single user who may not be paying attention to judge if the edit is good or bad. So if you were paying attention but the other reviewers were not, feel free to rollback (if they approved a bad edit like in this case) or to make the edit yourself (if the rejected a good edit).

There are a lot of robo-reviewers who approve everything they see just for the badges. As [Lundin pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360485/4284627), it seems like the users who approved this edit seem to be robo-reviewers, which means that they approved the edit just to review quickly to get badges and not because they really think it's a good edit. You were paying attention and noticed that the edit was useless, which is good, so it's perfectly OK for you to roll back that edit.

In this specific case, I don't really think that the edit does too much harm, even though it's completely useless. I would probably have rejected it as "no improvement whatsoever", but I might not have bothered to roll it back. But if you think that it's bad enough that it needs to get rolled back, you're welcome to do so. It's a bad edit, but I've seen worse edits get approved, and I rolled them back.

The most recent example of me rolling back a bad edit that got approved is [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18215878), which I found by looking at the review history of one of the users who approved the edit that you mentioned. This edit adds `code formatting` to keywords such as "Ubuntu 16" and "96 rows 2 columns" even though this is [against the rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/349538). The user who approved it "improved" it to add code formatting to "MATLAB" which is equally bad, so I rolled back both edits.

A few months ago, I rejected [another edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15264636) that abused code formatting and the edit later got approved, so I rolled it back. I think I also flagged for moderator attention so that a moderator could review ban the users who approved the edit and override the approval on other similar bad edits by that user that got approved.

I think it's also happened once that I saw a good edit getting rejected, so I made the edit myself. But that situation is a lot more rare, probably because it's faster to approve an edit than to reject it so robo-reviewers prefer approving edits.

---

So if you see a bad edit getting approved, it's perfectly OK to roll it back, it's even good if you do so. Additionally, if you see a *really* bad edit getting approved and you can find evidence on Meta and/or in the help center that such edits are considered bad, you might also want to flag for moderator attention so that a moderator can take appropriate actions against the user who suggested the edit and the users who approved it.

Comment: Also a good answer, thanks. Although I do reckon that `(A2:B97)` could still be a code formatted snip, but probably not important.

Comment: @MattFletcher Yes, formatting `(A2:B97)` as code was probably the only good thing that that edit did (maybe also `ssconvert`, I don't know enough about the topic to know if it's a function that should be formatted as code or a library name that shouldn't be formatted as code). Anyway, it wasn't enough to make up for the other changes that were bad.

Comment: `ssconvert` is a linux command that is (I think) built into Ubuntu. Not sure if that warrants code blocks or not. I tend to use them more than I should, but I think that if used sparingly it definitely helps readability for things that are not in the standard canon/lexicon

Comment: @MattFletcher: Pretty much anything you can type literally into a computer in source code or on a command prompt can use code formatting.  `ssconvert` is totally appropriate.  It can get tricky in cases like `gcc` is the compiler shell command itself, GCC is the GNU Compiler Collection.  So you could say `__attribute__((noinline))` is a GCC extension (to the C language), but you shouldn't say it's a `gcc` extension.